# Sqoop query from hive table to mysql

Tags: sqoop

Is there a way in sqoop to query data from hive table and write result to RDBMS table.

For example - I want to execute this query

```
SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM hivedbname.hivetablename
```

and write(insert or update) the result(in this case,the maximum date)to a table in MYSQL DB.

I know that we can use python or any other programming lang. to achieve this. But, I just want to know is this possible with sqoop.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `Sqoope export`

Comment: @SandeepSingh Can I execute the above query in sqoop export?

Comment: My bad, `--query` parameter  is not working with `sqoop export`  then you need to develop a custom solution i think.